# Uninstall Ubuntu 13.10 and install Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, windows-7

My problem started with Win7. it was all good till it got stuck on the windows sign and never went past that. checked the hardware but everything is in order. so i installed my favourite OS which is Ubuntu (13.10 in this case) as a dual so i won't lose my Win7 files.

I have been using ubuntu for a month now and now i get this send report notifications at the startup. it got more and more and became really annoying that it started getting stuck at startup.
Now i want to install Ubuntu 12.4 (hoping i wouldn't get those notifications), but i can't.

Here is the main issue. when i installed Ubuntu 13.10 i got a menu at the beginning to chose win7 or ubuntu (among other options). win7 doesn't work and ubuntu won't installed an older version of itself. i have the ubuntu system on USB but it appears i can't boot from it. i have tried all the functions while restarting. 
note that the i have chosen boot from USB as a primary.
My Laptop is an Asus.
If you have questions and suggestions i will be more than happy to answer and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

- You can disable the frequent appearance of the system crash/send report dialogue boxes.
  you need to edit `/etc/default/apport`

**Graphical**:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/apport
```

or

**Command line**:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/apport
```

Change enabled from "0" to a "1" so it looks like this:

```
enabled=1
```

To turn it off make it:

```
enabled=0
```

to turn it off at boot, and then turn it off with a `sudo service apport stop`

**Solution 2:**  Ubuntu don't restrict the installation of it's own older version.  Make sure the pendrive is bootable. 
An easier way to make a bootable USB of Ubuntu is by using [LinuxLive USB Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/)
Then try searching the web for 'how to boot a pendrive' with specifying your Laptop model. Make a Youtube search too.

Comment: Okay that was very clear and it worked, thank you. now i need to know how to mark this question closed.